нужно ли запятая "не зная чем заняться"
сидел, не зная чем заняться
или
не зная, чем заняться
подскажите, пожалуйста


Я бы не стала ставить запятую:

СидЕл, // не зная чем занЯться.
Пояснение
В данном предложении обобщенное значение устойчивого оборота (не зная что делать, не находя занятия).
Запятую нежелательно ставить и ПО СТРУКТУРЕ данного предложения: устойчивый оборот входит в деепричастный оборот. Соответственно, две части, две фонетические фразы. Делить деепричастный оборот на части не имеет смысла. Иначе получается избыток запятых  с точки зрения графики.

Но решение неочевидное, например:

№ 252525
Нужны ли запятые в предложениях ? "Я не знаю чем заняться сегодня" и "Я увидел как она вышла из подъезда."
ОТВЕТ.
В этих предложениях нужно поставить запятые.
№ 309990
Нужна ли запятая в предложении: Здесь каждый найдет, чем заняться.
ОТВЕТ.
Запятая нужна.
В этих примерах придаточное предложение с подчинительным союзом (с.с. чем).

Нет причин не ставить запятую: "Не зная, чем заняться, займитесь собой – и свет от вашего маяка притянет тех, с кем вам по пути".
Запятая внутри выражений
Запятая не ставится внутри выражений типа есть чем заняться, есть над чем поработать, было о чём подумать, найду куда обратиться, не нахожу что сказать, осталось на что жить, состоящих из глагола быть или найти (найтись), остаться и вопросительно-относительного местоимения или наречия (кто, что, где, куда, когда и т. д.) и неопределенной формы другого глагола: Тебе есть в мире что забыть (Л.); Бранить есть кому, кормить — некому (Даль); Есть чему и нравиться (Пис.); И нашу интеллигенцию есть за что любить, есть за что уважать (М.Г.); Есть над чем задуматься; Нашли чем удивить; Не нашёлся что сказать; У нас будет чем козырнуть; Нашла где модничать; Есть когда с тобой болтать!; Было отчего приуныть; Друзьям есть о чём поговорить; Ребятам было где проводить свободное время; Нам было в чём упрекнуть его.
